# Connection to remote db fails : Laravel application

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, database-migration

When I browse to http://192.168.1.12/phpmyadmin in my browser I'am able to login and see the db. But when i run the `php artisan migrate` command,
I am getting this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from
>   information     _schema.tables where table_schema = root and
>   table_name = migrations)
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

At the same time migartion to a local database is working.

Comment: Are you sure your database setting in your `.env` file are correct? I would check these first, make sure you're pointing to the correct IP of your database, etc.

Comment: db settings is correct.I'am trying to connect to a remote db(ip-192.168.1.12)

Comment: And the port number is correct? If you're connecting to a remote instance, are you sure it's configured to accept connections from the machine you're trying to connect to it from?

Comment: can you specify what all configurations is required.

Comment: What OS are you running? I'm assuming you're using MySQL as well, is that correct?

Comment: Are you on the same network? this is local ip range

Comment: @ Aaron Fahey Ubuntu 16.04, Yeah mysql

Comment: @aarun0207 yeah on the same network

Comment: are you able to use `mysql` client from the server and reach your other server... The database user is it allowed to connect from non localhost domain?

Comment: @Ken I can access http://192.168.1.12/phpmyadmin and can manage remote db from my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx port conflict at remote server. Also not reading .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can see based on your answer that you are trying to connect to a remote DB that PHPMyAdmin is installed on the machine you are connecting to but your Laravel app is not.

You need to edit the my.cnf (or my.ini if you are on Windows) and bind MySQL to the IP address (192.168.1.12).  You also need to restart MySQL and make sure that your MySQL user that you are using to connect from Laravel app has permissions (see below).

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO user@host IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```

You will need to flush privileges after as follows...

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You can use a wildcard in the host section of the grant in the event you are using DHCP.  A complete example would be as follows..

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO myuser@% IDENTIFIED BY 'secretpassword';
```

Comment: if you have completed all of the above steps make sure that the port is open.